# Azure OpenAI Nuget Package; Cannot add List of ChatMessage

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, azure-openai, azure-ai

##### What I am trying to do

I am trying to create a C# Web API (.NET 6) which uses the Azure.AI.OpenAI package.
I have the following code:

```cs
    public static async Task<ChatCompletions> Get(List<ChatMessage> messages)
    {
        OpenAIClient client = new OpenAIClient(
            new Uri("url"),
            new AzureKeyCredential(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY")));

        Response<ChatCompletions> responseWithoutStream = await client.GetChatCompletionsAsync(
            "modelname",
            new ChatCompletionsOptions()

            {
                Messages = messages,
                Temperature = (float)0.7,
                MaxTokens = 800,
                NucleusSamplingFactor = (float)0.95,
                FrequencyPenalty = 0,
                PresencePenalty = 0,
            });
        return responseWithoutStream.Value;
    }
```

##### Problem

While doing that everyone works out fine, except I get an error at the line, where I wrote: `Messages = messages`

For this I get the following error: `[CS0200] Property or indexer 'ChatCompletionsOptions.Messages' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`

I understand, that the Azure AI package is readonly, but I could not find any way to resolve this. Does anybody have a clue on resolving this?

##### What I have tried already

1. Looked up documentation
2. Checked the type of the receiving List and the expected List
3. Search for a different property or way to add the list to the Messages property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now found out, that you can just add the list of messages in the constructor of the ChatCompletionOptions.

It will look like the following:

```csharp
       Response<ChatCompletions> responseWithoutStream = await client.GetChatCompletionsAsync(
            _appSettings.Model, new ChatCompletionsOptions(messages) // The constructor takes in the messages.

            {
                Temperature = (float)0.7,
                MaxTokens = 800,
                NucleusSamplingFactor = (float)0.95,
                FrequencyPenalty = 0,
                PresencePenalty = 0
            });
```